# how can I use "INSERT SELECT" in symfony3?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I want to build query, where I insert data to mysql.

```
 $data=$request->request->all();
     $odd=$data['form']['odd'];
     $stake=$data['form']['stake'];
     $win=$data['form']['win'];
     $login_user=$data['form']['login_user'];

    $separator = '\r\n';

    $db = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = "INSERT INTO zakladyuser (game, type, odd, stake, win, login_user, stat)
              SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(game SEPARATOR :separator ), GROUP_CONCAT(type SEPARATOR :separator ), :odd, :stake, :win, :login_user, 0
              FROM kupon k0";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $params = array(
                    "separator"=>$separator,
                    "odd"=>$odd,
                    "stake"=>$stake,
                    "win"=>$win,
                    "login_user"=>$login_user
                  );
    $stmt->execute($params);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

What can I correct? Because I have these errors:

> Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::prepare()
>
> Attempted to call an undefined method named "prepare" of class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager".

And if this way is wrong, how can I do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `prepare()` in `connection` object:

```
$db = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
..
$stmt = $db->getConnection()->prepare($query);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I added it, and removed `$results = $stmt->fetchAll();` and now I can insert this data. 
But now I have problem with separators, these don't work, any ideas?

Comment: You are welcome! What do mean by "problem with separators"?

Comment: for example in column types: 1 [new line] 0 [new line] etc. It added me like that: `1\r\n0\r\n` etc.. But I fixed it, just changed it `$separator = '\r\n';` to `$separator = "\r\n";` :). But thanks again for help